# Why PyCharm can't import Gtk?

Tags: python-3.x, gtk, pygtk, pycharm

When I used `python2.7` everything was fine. When I change interpreter to `python3.2` PyCharm can't import Gtk. It prints "Unresolved reference". I'm trying import gtk with code

```
from gi.repository import Gtk
```

Comment: You need to import it as well. Go to the  terminal tab and do pip install pygObject or something like that and then import it